# Form validation without javascript

Tags: html, validation

I want to validate 7 alphanumeric for 1 part of my form but it keeps telling me to follow the format even when I use`pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]"`.

Here is my code :

```
<div class="control-group form-group">
    <div class="control">
        <label for="admin">Admin Number:
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="admin" name="admin" placeholder="eg. 123456A" required pattern="\[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}"/>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

and just asking but is it possible to validate radio box without javascript

Comment: Why `\[` instead of `[`?

Comment: I deleted it but it still keep saying Please match the requested format

Comment: @Norman - What is the value are you using that fails validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it to this and now it seems to be working:

```
<div class="control-group form-group">
<div class="control">
    <label for="admin">Admin Number:
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="admin" name="admin"  placeholder="eg. 123456A" pattern="[0-9A-Za-z]{7}"/>
</label>
</div>
</div>
```